# Create Mysql Storec Procedure via Python using Mysql Connector

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector, mysql-5.7

I Am builing a small application. where I Need to create MySQL Stored procedure via python using mysql Connector.

I have tried following code. But getting an following error that

> "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now."

I Am using MySQL Version `5.7.40-43-log`

Below is the python code snippet what I have tried.

```py
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host=HOST,user=USERNAME,passwd=PASSWORD,database=DBNAME,port=PORT,allow_local_infile=True)
cursor = mydb.cursor()

sqlquery = """DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS usp_myprocedure;

             DELIMITER //
                    
             CREATE PROCEDURE usp_myprocedure()
             BEGIN
                  TRUNCATE TABLE mytable;
                        
                   INSERT INTO mytable
                   SELECT col1
                          ,col2
                          ,col3
                          ,col4
                          ,CASE WHEN New_col='%_%' THEN logic1 
                                                   ELSE logic2 
                                END AS mylogic
                    FROM oldtable;
                        
                    SELECT * FROM mytable;
                        
             END //
                        
             DELIMITER ; 
             """

 cursor.execute(sqlquery)
 mydb.commit()
```

Above piece of MySQL code is working fine when running via Mysql Workbench. But while executing via python mysql connector getting an error `Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now.`

Any help would be Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This typically happens when you execute stored procedures or multiple statements that generate multiple result sets without fetching all of the rows of the previous result set(-s) - you can adjust your code to fetch all the result sets:

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host=HOST, user=USERNAME, passwd=PASSWORD, database=DBNAME, port=PORT, allow_local_infile=True
)
cursor = mydb.cursor()

# define sql query for creating the stored procedure
sqlquery = """
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS usp_myprocedure;
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_myprocedure()
BEGIN
    TRUNCATE TABLE mytable;

    INSERT INTO mytable
    SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4,
        CASE
            WHEN New_col='%_%' THEN logic1
            ELSE logic2
        END AS mylogic
    FROM oldtable;

    SELECT * FROM mytable;
END;
"""

# execute the query to create the stored procedure
cursor.execute(sqlquery)

# commit changes
mydb.commit()

# close the cursor and connection
cursor.close()
mydb.close()
```

Comment: I tried your suggession but got an error that `1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER //
                    
                    CREATE PROCEDURE usp_mypr' at line 1`

Comment: I tried the sql query in workbench, which is working fine

Comment: I've just adjusted the code and got rid off the delimiter, since in client libraries like mysql.connector, you typically don't need to change the delimiter.

Comment: Small note for others reference, I moved drop procedure commands out of the statement and executed separately before stored procedure creation script. 
`cursor.execute('DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS usp_myprocedure')
        mydb.commit()`. rest of the code remains same. Command didn't work If i keep the drop command and create command in the same sqlquery.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions to the code snippet:

1. Remove the `DELIMITER` statement because not all MySQL clients support `DELIMITER` statement e.g. [mysql-connector-python](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-python/tree/8.3.0).
2. `multi` option should be enabled for multiple SQL statements.
3. [iterate the returned generator](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-python/blob/8.3.0/mysql-connector-python/lib/mysql/connector/connection.py#L871) to ensure that results from the server are handled

```py
for result in cursor.execute('''
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS usp_myprocedure;


CREATE PROCEDURE usp_myprocedure()
BEGIN
  TRUNCATE TABLE test;
  INSERT INTO test
    SELECT id, CASE WHEN id=1 THEN 2 ELSE 2 END AS val
    FROM test2;
  SELECT * FROM test;
END
''', multi=True):
    pass

result = cursor.execute('''
CALL usp_myprocedure();
''')
print(result.fetchall())
```